# How can I properly route my .Net 6 controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I am building a calendar web application and for some reason my API is unable to be called from both a fetch in my Javascript file and from Postman.

I tried routing using `System.Net.Http` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Http`. I added and removed the prefix.

From my understanding the URL as it stands should be

```
https://localhost:****/api/post
```

but that returns a 404 both from the dev console by a Javascript fetch and postman.

[Here is an image of the code as is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfipm.png)

[here is an Image of the fetch in my JS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU97E.png)]

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read the tutorial and the guide in order to learn how to ask, and avoid code in images. Take your time, you need to help us to help you

Comment: @lifelsgood: Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Answer (score 1):

> I am building a calendar web application and for some reason my API is
> unable to be called from both a fetch in my Javascript file and from
> Postman but that returns a 404 both from the dev console by a
> Javascript fetch and postman.

Well, because of using `[RoutePrefix("api")]` before your `CalenderEventsController`  it is certainly overriding your application standard routing. So, your controller route has been changed. Thus, you should use routing as [`[Route("api/[controller]")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-and-url-paths)

**Correct Way:**

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CalenderEventsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CalenderDbContext _context;
        
        public RoleRepository(CalenderDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(CalenderEvent calender)
        {

            return Ok(calender);

        }
    }
```

**Note:** I would highly recommend you to have a look on our official document for [Routing and URL paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-and-url-paths) and [Custom route constraints.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-route-constraints)